# Adding content changes the layout in my code. Why?

Tags: css

the following code makes a layout. It fits nicely, but when I add content (for example between the article tags) the "box" where I added the content moves. I can't explain it well but you can try it here https://codepen.io/davidp00/pen/XpjRgW . Just changing

```
<article></article>
```

to

```
<article>blabla</article>
```

changes the layout.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
    }
    /* main sections */
    header {
        height: calc(10% - 2px);
    }

    footer {
        height: calc(10% - 2px);
    }

    .container {
        height: calc(80% - 2px);
    }

    header, footer, .container {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    /* inside container */

    nav, article, aside {
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: calc(100% - 2px);
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    article {
        width: calc(70% - 2px);
    }

    nav {
        width: calc(10% - 2px);
    }

    aside {
        width: calc(20% - 2px);
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header></header>
    <div class="container">
        <nav></nav><!--
     --><article></article><!--
     --><aside></aside>
    </div>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I think `display: inline-block;` causes this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by the comments, it is the use of `display: inline-block` that is causing the issue. Remember that this display mode uses a mix of inline and block level layouts, meaning that when a text node is present, it will align the baseline with the bottom of surrounding text. To circumvent this, use `float: left` (which will force `display: block` anyway) instead of using `display: inline-block`.

Also, it is probably easier to use `box-sizing: border-box`, so that you do not have to manually recalculate/readjust the width declarations due to changes in border widths.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}
/* main sections */
header {
    height: 10%;
}

footer {
    height: 10%;
}

.container {
    height: 80%;
}

header, footer, .container {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

/* inside container */

nav, article, aside {
  box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

article {
  background-color: red;
    width: 70%;
}

nav {
    width: 10%;
}

aside {
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div class="container">
      <nav></nav><!--
   --><article>a</article><!--
   --><aside></aside>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
```